# Insert and update data in table using Java Persistence Query Language

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need to update and insert data in table using Java Persistence Query Language. Here is my DAO class code:

```
public class ApprovalDao {


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void addEntity(EntityValues entity) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }


    public void deleteEntityValue(EntityValues entity) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }
```

Comment: What are the problem? some exceptions?

Comment: Where are other classes and what have you tried so far?

Comment: JPQL relates to JPA. You're not using JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for updating data of fields in table :

```
public void updateField(){
    Query q=getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(
        " update SapOrderHDR set
            SAP_ORDER_STATUS = 'A' where BC_ORDER_NO='" + bcOrderNo + "'");
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```

This query will update table where `BC_ORDER_NO=var` and `set BC_ORDER_NO ='A'`. 
 `SapOrderHDR` is table entity class

Comment: Don't do this, this is vulnerable to SQL Injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use `BC_ORDER_NO = :no` and `q.setParameter("no", bcOrderNo)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you use `@Autowired` annotation `setter/getteer` methods are redundant. In your case you should youse something like this:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.update(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And surround it with `try/catch` construction.

Comment: Redundant? you mean innecesary?

Comment: Redundant and unnecesary aren't synonyms?